# jQuery Find not finding element in HTML template

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik

I have a telerik KendoUI template which I load into a jQuery object.  That is working.

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="customKeywordsEditorPopup">
    Custom Keywords
    <input style="width:100%" id="inpKeywords"/>
</script>
```

Now here is the JavaScript code which does not give me the expected result:

```
         var popupHtml = $("#customKeywordsEditorPopup"); //This works

         alert($(popupHtml).html()); //This outputs the HTML as expected
         alert($(popupHtml).find('#inpKeywords').length); //This returns 0 instead of 1
```

Unfortunately, $(popupHtml).find('#inpKeywords') does NOT return an actual element.  It should reference the INPUT.

Any idea why this is not working?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(popupHtml).find('#inpKeywords').length
```

Returns 0 because there are no elements within your `<script>` tag. Text inside `<script>` tags are not rendered as html.

In order for your template to become html you have to pass it through kendo, pass it as html to the container of your choice, and finally you can then select it with your id selector

```
var template = kendo.template($("#customKeywordsEditorPopup").html());
$("#SomeContainer").html(template({}));
var input = $("#inpKeywords");
```

Demo

```js
var templateText = $("#customKeywordsEditorPopup").text();

var template = kendo.template(templateText);
$("#SomeContainer").html(template({}));
var input = $("#inpKeywords");
input.val('Some value');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link ref="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/styles/kendo.all.min.css">

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="customKeywordsEditorPopup">
  Custom Keywords
  <input style="width:100%" id="inpKeywords" />
</script>

<div id="SomeContainer"></div>
```